# How to proxy spring milestone repo using nexus

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, nexus

I want to proxy the spring milestone repository using nexus.

Can anybody tell me the correct url to use.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. This is it:

```
<repository>
    <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
    <name>Maven Central Compatible Spring Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>http:// maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>
```

For reference, see this blog post:
[Obtaining Spring 3 Artifacts with Maven](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/)

Comment: Thanks!  It seems to work, but why can't i browse the remote repository in nexus ?

Comment: Because it's a non-browsable cloud server. But you should be able to build an index of it anyway. BTW, if you like my answer, please upvote and / or accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Sean is good, but you should try with `https`, because for me with `http` gives 403:

```
<repository>
    <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
    <name>Maven Central Compatible Spring Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>https://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>
```

A move is being made from HTTP to HTTPS for all major maven repos:

https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2020/java/Your-Java-builds-might-break-starting-January-13th.html